# How to use AppleScript to un-hide a file's extension?

Tags: macos, applescript, file-extensions

In Finder, if you right click a file → *Get Info*, you will see a checkbox in the *Name & Extension* section that offers users the ability to *Hide extension*.

If you press Command (⌘)-Shift-3 to take a whole-screen screenshot on your Mac, a screenshot is saved as a .png file. By default, the .png extension for a screenshot is hidden.

Can I change this hide extension status using AppleScript?

---

If you are curious as to why I'm trying to perform this action in AppleScript, it is because I have a script that involves taking & saving a screenshot, and then naming the file based on the text on the clipboard. And, in this process of renaming the file, Finder no longer recognizes the file as a .png file, so I have to manually change the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind! I found the answer here:

[Super User: Show/hide extension of a file through OS X command line](https://superuser.com/questions/399899/show-hide-extension-of-a-file-through-os-x-command-line)

I will delete this question now!

EDIT -

Since some are upvoting this question, I will echo the [top answer](https://superuser.com/a/399918) in the linked question (supplied by @slhck).

A straightforward solution exists, because AppleScript specifically offers a `set extension hidden` command designed to do exactly what I'm looking for.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set some_file to (choose file)
    set extension hidden of some_file to false
end tell
```

And that will make the file extension visible!

Comment: Rather than delete - maybe explain the script here and keep the link to the other answer?

Comment: Are you sure? I know how strongly SE frowns upon redundancy, and the question linked is practically identical to mine.

Comment: @rubik'ssphere Well... Um... True... (Problem with when site topics overlap each other.)

Comment: Note: It is necessary to insert `file` before the file path when one is not using `(choose file)` to get the file. Source: [_AppleScript: How to un-hide the file extension of a screenshot?_](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271487/applescript-how-to-un-hide-the-file-extension-of-a-screenshot/271494#271494)