# AppleScript: How to un-hide the file extension of a screenshot?

Tags: macos, applescript, file-extensions

```
set filePath to "/Users/Me/Desktop/" & "Screenshot" & ".png"

do shell script "screencapture -mx -T1 " & filePath

tell application "Finder"
    set extension hidden of (filePath as POSIX file) to false
end tell
```

The above code produces the error:

> Finder got an error: Can’t set extension hidden of file "Macintosh
>   HD:Users:Me:Desktop:Screenshot.png" to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close! You need to use `file` in front of `(filePath as POSIX file)`, e.g.:

```
set filePath to "/Users/Me/Desktop/" & "Screenshot" & ".png"

do shell script "screencapture -mx -T1 " & filePath

tell application "Finder"
    set extension hidden of file (filePath as POSIX file) to false
end tell
```